# Storage manager function to read block of a file

Tags: c, storage, fread, file-handling, fseek

I am implementing a storage manager to open, create, read and write a file using file pointers and file handler. But i am not able to write efficient code to implement all of my read functions of my storage manager. The read function of my storage manager has  to implement the following:

1. To read first block of a file
2. To read current block of a file
3. To read previous block of a file
4. To read next block of a file
5. To read last block of a file

Any suggestions and code examples would be helpful to me.
The following is the code written by me to read a data file using file pointer -
    */
     #include 
     #include

```
 void main()
{ 
 FILE *fptr;
 char filename[15];
 char ch;

 printf("Enter the filename to be opened \n");
 scanf("%s", filename);
 /*  open the file for reading */
 fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
 if (fptr == NULL)
 {
     printf("Cannot open file \n");
     exit(0);
 }
 ch = fgetc(fptr);
 while (ch != EOF)
 {
    printf ("%c", ch);
    ch = fgetc(fptr);
 }
 fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far, and how is it inefficient?

Comment: Your recent efforts on the subject will show, where the help can direct you to continue.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to reinvent a wheel, namely, basic operating system functions called `open`, `creat`, `read`, `write`, `seek`, `close`. You should ask yourself why do you need to create this bogus wrapper